# What is the graph of this?

Tags: functions

I need know what is the graph of y=y(x), where:
$\sqrt {{{(x - \sqrt 5 )}^2} + {y^2}}  + \sqrt {{{(x + \sqrt 5 )}^2} + {y^2}}  = 6$ , 
thank you

Comment: An ellipse is the locus of points $P$ such that the sum of the distances of $P$ from two fixed points $A$ and $B$ is constant. Please see Wikipedia for details. In your particular example, you can get to a standard-looking ellipse equation by manipulation.

Comment: what theorems can you use?

Answer (score 2):

with some Algebra we can solve your problem:
First time squaring: 
$(x-\sqrt{5})^2+(x+\sqrt{5})^2+2y^2=2\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{5})^2+y^2}\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{5})^2+y^2}=36$
simplifying we get
$\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{5})^2+y^2}\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{5})^2+y^2}=13-x^2-y^2$
squaring again we obtain
$4x^2+9y^2=36$    or
$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$

Answer (score 1):

A formula can be derived from the fact that the sum of the distances from any point $P = P(x,y)$ on the ellipse to those two foci, say $F_1$ and $F_2$, is constant and equal to the major axis.
$$PF_1 + PF_2 = \sqrt {{{(x - f )}^2} + {y^2}}  + \sqrt {{{(x + f )}^2} + {y^2}}  = 2a $$
where $f$ is the distance from the center to either focus and $a$ is the major radius (the radius which is along the $x$-axis).

[Refer this Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_ellipse) to get from the above formula to the cartesian equation.

Here's my working ::

$$
\begin{align}
6 &= \sqrt{(x-\sqrt 5)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x+\sqrt 5)^2 + y^2}\\
&= \sqrt{x^2 - 2x\sqrt 5 + \sqrt{5}^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 2x\sqrt 5 + \sqrt{5}^2 + y^2}\\
&= \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + 5) - (2\sqrt 5 \cdot x)\,} + \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + 5) + (2\sqrt 5 \cdot x)}
\end{align}$$
Using the fact that $ \mathcal{ C = \sqrt{ A - B } + \sqrt{A + B} \iff  A = \left(\frac{B}{C}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)^2 }$,

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 5 = \left(\frac{2\sqrt 5 \cdot x}{6}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{6}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{5x^2}{9} + 9\\
\implies \frac{9-5}{9} x^2 + y^2 = 9 - 5\\
\implies\left( \frac{x}{3}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 = 1$$

The graph is an ellipse having

- Major radius : $a\ =\ 3$
- Minor radius : $b\ =\ 2$
- Focal length : $f\ =\ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\ =\ \sqrt{3^2 - 2^2}\ =\ \sqrt{5}$

[image: elipse]

If you have any difficulty plotting the graph now, [PatrickJMT will teach you](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nxT6LQhXLM).